# Php - Copy Stream to itself

Tags: php, stream

I'd like to perform an operation on the `php://input` stream but also return it.

For example, what I'd like to achieve is that:

`php://input ==> OPERATION ==> php://input`

Is that possible to make something like that ?

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
$output = fopen("php://input", "w");
while (($buffer.= fgets($input, 1024)) !== false) {
  // Do something with that buffer
  // ??
  fwrite($output, $buffer);

}
fclose($output);
fclose($input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with one of the operations supported as a [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.php) in php, you can use the `php://filter` [fopen wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Let's say you want to base64 decode the data for example:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://filter/read=convert.base64-decode/resource=php://input');
```

Or:

```
$input = fopen('php://filter/read=convert.base64-decode/resource=php://input');
// now you can pass $input to somewhere and every read operation will 
// return base64 decoded data ...
```

---

However, the set of operations supported as a filter in PHP is quite limited. If it does not fit your needs I would suggest to wrap the file pointer, in a class maybe. Here comes a very basic example, you might add buffering, caching or whatever...

```
class Input {

    public static function read() {
        return $this->process(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
    }


    public function process($data) {
        return do_whatever_with($data);
    }

}
```

Then in the application code use:

```
$input = Input::read();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but by `customer operation` I mean, add or remove content. This is a bit more complicated than b64 encode/decode.

Comment: Ah. Your question was a bit unclear on this, so I thought this might be of interest. Unfortunately the set of available filters is quite limited. Let me try to give an alternative ...

Comment: This would probably work if the data length is under the RAM size. But what if I transfer 20GB through the stream ?

Comment: Then you cannot use file_get_contents anymore (unless you have 20GB memory : ) You need to perform the read operation in a loop. But this can be also encapsulated in a class. Of course your class code would need to inspect all the 20GB in order to find the place to edit the data. In most cases the answer on a real world, 20GB sized problem is not using PHP at all but other techniques like database server for example.